# Python: Failed to Launch Debug Adapter, Operation was cancelled. Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-2022

So I've seen that many people have asked this question before, but it's always in relation to a different framework/language.

I was working on a solution in python and seemingly for no reason I couldn't debug anymore.

I opened a new solution to see if I had somehow broken my solution, but now I can't debug at all.

The programs do however execute just fine.

[image: VS Error with the most basic code]

I've tried all of the suggested fixes I could find:

-Restart PC

-Open the De-bug options, Enabling JS debugging for ASP NET (Even though I'm working in python)

-Repairing VS

-Completely Uninstalling VS and Re-installing

-Looking for the path C:\Users\username\vsdbg\ (Doesn't exist)

I suspect there has been some kind of conflict between 2019 vs and 2022 VS but I'm certain I've removed all of the old files related to 2019

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I've managed to fix:
Looks like the issue was coming from the version of Python that the solution was attempting to de-bug with.

1. Drop down the Python environment selector,
2. Navigate to existing environment
3. Select the latest version of python environment [(Make sure you have it downloaded and installed correctly)](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

[Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNbPv.png)

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider changing its status to Answered. See can I answer my own question.., Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. What I did to solve it was to use a newer Python version. I was using Python 3.6. It looks like VS does not support Python 3.6 anymore - see [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7615).